# How to make Python code executable and how to read the .exe file directory inside the code?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a Python code executable so that the colleagues who do not have Python installed in their PCs can use it as well. Now, I have 2 questions:
1- How to make the Python code executable?
2- How to search for a specific format (lets say CSV) file in the directory of the exe file? I think this will require the directory to be detected first, then search within that directory for any file with the .csv format and read it.

Thank you,

Comment: As for CSVs, you should ask in a seperate question but consider the CSV library and using built in classes like os and sys to browse files local to the install.